# How to save/restore large model in tensorflow 2.0 w/ keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I have a large custom model made with the new tensorflow 2.0 and mixing keras and tensorflow. I want to save it (architecture and weights).
Exact command to reproduce:

```py
import tensorflow as tf


OUTPUT_CHANNELS = 3

def downsample(filters, size, apply_batchnorm=True):
  initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer(0., 0.02)

  result = tf.keras.Sequential()
  result.add(
      tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters, size, strides=2, padding='same',
                             kernel_initializer=initializer, use_bias=False))

  if apply_batchnorm:
    result.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())

  result.add(tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU())

  return result

def upsample(filters, size, apply_dropout=False):
  initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer(0., 0.02)

  result = tf.keras.Sequential()
  result.add(
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters, size, strides=2,
                                    padding='same',
                                    kernel_initializer=initializer,
                                    use_bias=False))

  result.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())

  if apply_dropout:
      result.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))

  result.add(tf.keras.layers.ReLU())

  return result


def Generator():
  down_stack = [
    downsample(64, 4, apply_batchnorm=False), # (bs, 128, 128, 64)
    downsample(128, 4), # (bs, 64, 64, 128)
    downsample(256, 4), # (bs, 32, 32, 256)
    downsample(512, 4), # (bs, 16, 16, 512)
    downsample(512, 4), # (bs, 8, 8, 512)
    downsample(512, 4), # (bs, 4, 4, 512)
    downsample(512, 4), # (bs, 2, 2, 512)
    downsample(512, 4), # (bs, 1, 1, 512)
  ]

  up_stack = [
    upsample(512, 4, apply_dropout=True), # (bs, 2, 2, 1024)
    upsample(512, 4, apply_dropout=True), # (bs, 4, 4, 1024)
    upsample(512, 4, apply_dropout=True), # (bs, 8, 8, 1024)
    upsample(512, 4), # (bs, 16, 16, 1024)
    upsample(256, 4), # (bs, 32, 32, 512)
    upsample(128, 4), # (bs, 64, 64, 256)
    upsample(64, 4), # (bs, 128, 128, 128)
  ]

  initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer(0., 0.02)
  last = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(OUTPUT_CHANNELS, 4,
                                         strides=2,
                                         padding='same',
                                         kernel_initializer=initializer,
                                         activation='tanh') # (bs, 256, 256, 3)

  concat = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()

  inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=[None,None,3])
  x = inputs

  # Downsampling through the model
  skips = []
  for down in down_stack:
    x = down(x)
    skips.append(x)

  skips = reversed(skips[:-1])

  # Upsampling and establishing the skip connections
  for up, skip in zip(up_stack, skips):
    x = up(x)
    x = concat([x, skip])

  x = last(x)

  return tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x)

generator = Generator()
generator.summary()

generator.save('generator.h5')
generator_loaded = tf.keras.models.load_model('generator.h5')
```

I manage to save the model with:

```
generator.save('generator.h5')
```

But when I try to load it with:

```
generator_loaded = tf.keras.models.load_model('generator.h5')
```

It never ends (no error message). Maybe the model is too large? I tried to save as JSON with `model.to_json()` as well as the full API `tf.keras.models.save_model()`, but same problem, impossible to load it (or at least far too long).

Same problem on Windows/Linux and with/without GPU.

The save and restore work well with full Keras and simple model.

## Edit

- Saving weights and then loading them works well, but it's impossible to load the model structure.
- I put the model I use to reproduce the bug, it comes from Pix2Pix example (https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/tutorials/generative/pix2pix)
- I also wrote an issue on tensorflow github : https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/28281

Comment: How long before you are stopping it?

Comment: TensorFlow 2.0 is still currently an alpha release, it has bugs, you shouldn't be using it for normal development. Maybe report this bug and move to a stable TF version.

Comment: Few minutes. Yes, I know it's just an an alpha release, but it may be a mistake on my side.

Answer (score 2):

As of tensorflow release 2.0.0 there is now a keras / tf agnostic way of saving models using tf.saved_model

```
        ....

        model.fit(images, labels , epochs=30, validation_data=(images_val, labels_val), verbose=1)

        tf.saved_model.save( model, "path/to/model_dir" )
```

You can then load with

```
        loaded_model = tf.saved_model.load("path/to/model_dir")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try instead to save the model as:

```
model.save('model_name.model')
```

Then Load it with:

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model_name.model')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, same problem, impossible to load it (at least too long, I stopped it before).

Comment: @Ridane Why not pickle it instead?

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporary solution. 
It seems that the issue occurs with the sequential API `tf.keras.Sequential`, by using the functional API, `tf.keras.models.load_model` manages to load the saved model.
I hope they will fixed this issue in the final release, have a look to the issue I raised in github https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/28281.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

I managed to save and load custom models by implementing similar functions to the Sequential model in Keras.

The key functions are `CustomModel.get_config()` `CustomModel.from_config()`, which also should exist on any of your custom layers (similar to the functions below, but see keras layers if you want a better understanding):

```py
# In the CustomModel class    
def get_config(self):
    layer_configs = []
    for layer in self.layers:
        layer_configs.append({
            'class_name': layer.__class__.__name__,
            'config': layer.get_config()
        })
    config = {
        'name': self.name,
        'layers': copy.deepcopy(layer_configs),
        "arg1": self.arg1,
        ...
    }
    if self._build_input_shape:
        config['build_input_shape'] = self._build_input_shape
    return config

@classmethod
def from_config(cls, config, custom_objects=None):
    from tensorflow.python.keras import layers as layer_module
    if custom_objects is None:
        custom_objects = {'CustomLayer1Class': CustomLayer1Class, ...}
    else:
        custom_objects = dict(custom_objects, **{'CustomLayer1Class': CustomLayer1Class, ...})

    if 'name' in config:
        name = config['name']
        build_input_shape = config.get('build_input_shape')
        layer_configs = config['layers']
    else:
        name = None
        build_input_shape = None
        layer_configs = config
    model = cls(name=name,
                arg1=config['arg1'],
                should_build_graph=False,
                ...)
    for layer_config in tqdm(layer_configs, 'Loading Layers'):
        layer = layer_module.deserialize(layer_config,
                                         custom_objects=custom_objects)
        model.add(layer) # This function looks at the name of the layers to place them in the right order
    if not model.inputs and build_input_shape:
        model.build(build_input_shape)
    if not model._is_graph_network:
        # Still needs to be built when passed input data.
        model.built = False
    return model
```

I also added a `CustomModel.add()` function that adds layers one by one from their config. Also a parameter `should_build_graph=False` that makes sure you do not build the graph in the `__init__()` when calling `cls()`.

Then the `CustomModel.save()` function looks like this:

```py
    def save(self, filepath, overwrite=True, include_optimizer=True, **kwargs):
        from tensorflow.python.keras.models import save_model  
        save_model(self, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer)
```

After that you can save using:

```py
model.save("model.h5")
new_model = keras.models.load_model('model.h5',
                                        custom_objects={
                                        'CustomModel': CustomModel,                                                     
                                        'CustomLayer1Class': CustomLayer1Class,
                                        ...
                                        })
```

But somehow this approach seem to be quite slow... This approach on the other hand is almost 30x faster. Not sure why:

```py
    model.save_weights("weights.h5")
    config = model.get_config()
    reinitialized_model = CustomModel.from_config(config)
    reinitialized_model.load_weights("weights.h5")
```

I works, but it seems quite hacky. Maybe future versions of TF2 will make the process clearer.

Answer (score -1):

One other method of saving a trained model is to use the `pickle` module in python.

```
import pickle
pickle.dump(model, open(filename, 'wb'))
```

In order to load the `pickled` model,

```
loaded_model = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))
```

The extension of the pickle file is usually `.sav`

Comment: Does not work either : "TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects"

Comment: There is a work around for that error in the following link. Why not give it a shot?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44855603/typeerror-cant-pickle-thread-lock-objects-in-seq2seq

Comment: Also how big was the h5 file? Couple of Gigabytes at the least i suppose ?

Comment: The *.h5 file for this one from example is 212 722Ko. Yes I could give it a shot with the pickle module. But i'd rather use the tensorflow API in a clean way, and I don't think that the size is the issue here, it seems to be deeper. In my opinion, lot of people will use the keras.save API, therefore I wrote an issue on tensorflow github here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/28281 :)